# Recursive call in merge sort confusion

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

Here is the code:

```
def mergeSort(myList):
    if len(myList) > 1:
        mid = len(myList) // 2
        left = myList[:mid]
        right = myList[mid:]

        # Recursive call on each half
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        # Two iterators for traversing the two halves
        i = 0
        j = 0
        
        # Iterator for the main list
        k = 0
        
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
              # The value from the left half has been used
              myList[k] = left[i]
              # Move the iterator forward
              i += 1
            else:
                myList[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            # Move to the next slot
            k += 1

        # For all the remaining values
        while i < len(left):
            myList[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            myList[k]=right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

myList = [2,4,1,5,3]
mergeSort(myList)
print(myList)
```

My doubt is that the mergeSort(left) and mergeSort(right) functions are called but no return statement is there so how is the order of the list changing how is  the changed list even returned back to the function there is no return statement.Ps:I am still a beginner so please try to simplify it for me Thanks

Comment: We don't want to return any array or list here as we pass the array and it gets changed after every recursive call in place. You can visit this link to know more about mergesort : [Link](https://youtu.be/TzeBrDU-JaY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no return statement is there so how is the order of the list changing

It is being changed at every instance where an assignment to `myList[k]` happens. Since this really is the list that the caller has provided to your function, any change to its values will be noted by the caller.

The caller would *not* know if the function would have assigned a new value to `myList` itself (like with `myList = []`), but when it is *mutated* (with `myList[k] = ...`) then this *mutates* the list of the caller. The function and the caller are accessing the *same* list.

> how is the changed list even returned back

It is not returned back. This is what *in-place* sorting is doing: the function does not create a new list to copy the values into in sorted order -- in which case it would have to *return* that list to the caller. No, with *in-place* sorting, the values in the list itself are moved around, affecting the *one* list that the caller owns.

So after the function has run to completion, the caller can inspect the list and see that now it is sorted.

### Hybrid situation

Now, with a typical merge sort, there are other, temporary lists created, but they only serve for setting aside some values, but they do get moved back into the caller's list, after which those temporary lists become obsolete.

For instance, here two new lists are created with a copy of values from the given list:

```
left = myList[:mid]
right = myList[mid:]
```

These are both mutated (sorted) by recursive calls:

```
mergeSort(left)
mergeSort(right)
```

But then the remainder of the function is dedicated to copy values from the (sorted) `left` and `right` lists into the caller's list (`myList`), so that in the end `left` and `right` are no longer needed, and `myList` is sorted.

Comment: can you please send a link or something so that i can understand this 'in-place sorting' better... the fact that the older list which is sent to the function is not changing is confusing me

Comment: What do you mean with the "older" list? The list that is passed to the function *is* changing.

Comment: Based on what you told ....when the recursive function is called and the changes which are made on the list by the recursive function will be reflected back afte the end of the function right?

Comment: Yes, the changes will be seen in the list *that was passed as argument* to that recursive function call.